# PERL 'e' (eval) within REGEX error when using lt (<)

Tags: regex, perl

I am using a one liner from the command line to do a REGEX substitution. This works:

```
perl -pe 's/<span class="num">(\d\d?)/<span class="num">+$1 + 1/eg' calendar1.html  > output.html
```

But when I add `<td>` to the beginning I get error:

```
perl -pe 's/<td><h3 class="day"><span class="num">(\d\d?)/<td><h3 class="day"><span class="num"> +$1 + 1/eg' calendar1.html  > output.html
```

Error:

```
Can't modify numeric lt (<) in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near "1}"
```

The html structure I am trying to match looks like this:

```
<td>
      <h3 class="day"><span class="num">10
```

I am trying to 1 to each one or two digit number

Comment: The first line doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have corrected the first one to one that works, apologies, this may have confused the question

Answer (score 0):

With `/e`, the replacement must be a Perl expression.

My Perl (5.20.1) complains about `<span class="num">$1 + 1`, and I think it's right: that's not an expression. Add quotes and concatenation where needed:

```
s/<span class="num">+(\d)/q(<span class="num">) . ($1 + 1)/eg
```

Similarly, for the second expression:

```
s/<td><h3 class="day"><span class="num">(\d\d?)/q(<td><h3 class="day"><span class="num">) . ($1 + 1)/eg
```

or shorter

```
s/(<td><h3 class="day"><span class="num">)(\d\d?)/$1 . ($2 + 1)/eg
```

Comment: Since 5.10, `s/<td><h3 class="day"><span class="num">\K(\d\d?)/$1 + 1/eg`

Comment: I get the error: syntax error near unexpected token `<' on both of these

Answer (score 0):

choroba pipped me to the answer: /e takes an expression; try something like this:

`echo '<td> <h3 class="day"><span class="num">10' | perl -pe 's/<td>\s*<h3\s+class="day"><span\s+class="num">(\d\d?)/"<td><h3 class=\"day\"><span class=\"num\">".($1+1)/ge'`

Comment: This works but when applying to a file, I cannot get this to recognize the newline and whitespace in such a structure as:
   <td>(newline here as in original code example)
          <h3 class="day"><span class="num">14
.....Using singularly or any combination of the following: "/n or /r or /s* " does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: the /n, /r and /s* in the above comment should be \n, \r, and \s*

Comment: Missed you're reply; if you're having trouble with whitespace and newlines then try replacing the spaces above with \W* and you might also need the /s modifier, so change the /ge to /ges.